# Aplicando automapper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, automapper

Hola tengo un método en el cual aplico automaper pero me sale el siguiente error:
No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo DGVdto con ProveedorExtend
Si ambos tienen las misma propiedades.

```
public class ProveedorExtend 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
public class DGVdto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

A que se debe el error

```
public List<ProveedorExtend> GetProveedor()
    {
        List<ProveedorExtend> _proveedor = _sdproveedor.GetProveedor();
        List<DGVdto> listDto = Mapper.Map<List<ProveedorExtend>, List<DGVdto>>(_proveedor);
        return **listDto**; Error arriba en mención.
    }
```

Este es el nuevo método

```
public List<DGVdto> GetProveedor()
    {
        List<ProveedorExtend> _proveedor = _sdproveedor.GetProveedor();
        config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ProveedorExtend, DGVdto>());
        List<DGVdto> listDto = config.CreateMapper().Map<List<DGVdto>>(_proveedor);
        return listDto;
    }
```

_proveedor trae registros, pero no se los puedo pasar a listDto, que estoy haciendo mal?
ListDto viene vacío.

Comment: que version de automapper estas usando? como defines el CreateMap() ?

Comment: te recomiendo leer el post de un buen amigo mio: http://somostechies.com/usando-automapper-para-generar-proyecciones-en-linq-to-entities/#.Vx-w7EcYNLs

Comment: Version 4.2.0 no puse un CreateMap(), te refieres a esto antes de mi segunda linea de código Mapper.CreateMap<List<ProveedorExtend>, List<DGVdto>>(); mew dice esta absoleto

Comment: porque cambio la forma en como usas automapper, deberias leer la documentacion https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Por curiosidad, qué quieres lograr?

Comment: Hola fredyfx, lo que pasa es que estoy cargando una sola grilla con diferentes entidades y cuando lo llame desde la presentación quiero hacer una sola lista la cual la declaro a nivel de formulario y lo puedo usar en todos los metodos para cargar la grilla y tambien para hacer un list.remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como veras en el ejemplo

```
MapperConfiguration config;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ProveedorExtend, DGVdto>());

}

public List<DGVdto> GetProveedor()
{
    List<ProveedorExtend> _proveedor = new List<ProveedorExtend>();

    List<DGVdto> listDto = config.CreateMapper().Map<List<DGVdto>>(_proveedor);

    return listDto;
}
```

la forma de mapear cambio en las ultimas versiones.

En el `Map<>()` si defines de entrada un `List<ProveedorExtend>` la salida no puede ser la misma, por eso cambie el tipo devuelto por el metodo `GetProveedor()`

[Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: Leandro ¿se instala automapper en la capa de presentación? por que veo que lo usas en el load.

Comment: es solo un ejemplo, se supone que debes poder acceder a la instancia del MapperConfiguration para poder obtener el mapper que aplicara la conversion

Comment: listDto no trae nada.

Comment: pero _proveedor tiene item que convertir ?

Comment: Solo quiero cargart la lista listDto

Comment: si eso habia quedado claro, pero la lista que asignas de entrada (_proveedor) para mapear contiene items ?

Comment: Leandro, lo agregue en la pregunta principal del nuevo método